# What is the difference between "Git" in general and Github?

Tags: git, github, version-control, dvcs

I know that Github is the most common site programmers use to save and make changes to code, but is this the only software out there? What are other relevant sites that utilize "Git" or version control that I could use?

Comment: Git is a protocol-specification for a distributed version control system. There are several different Git implementations, including a/the reference. The command-line program is called "git". Github is a site that hosts centralized Git ("master") repositories and adds social / "distributed collaboration" features. Bitbucket Server is a competitor - sort of. But, recommendations for sites is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

**Git** is a distributed version control system. More simpler description: it is tool that helps to manage repo with sources.

Wiht purpose to share your repo with other project participants you need a public server where will be hosted your git repo.

**GitHub** it is web service that provide to you an opportunity to host your repo. You can host it like public or private repo. Also GitHub provide a lot of other helpful features (convenient code-review tool, edit files, manage team, graphs, wiki, gist, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

"Git" is version control system that can use different hosts as server. Many companies use local "Git" servers.
Github is one of many public "Git" servers, but it is most popular one.